# Request запрос выдает ошибку при попытке загрузки изображения с сайта

Tags: python, request

Вот мой код:

```
import requests, bs4, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
      }

for i in range(1, 40):
    url = 'https://www.drom.ru/pdd/bilet_' + str(i)
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    images = soup.find_all('img', class_='b-image b-image__image')
    print(images)

    for urlImage in images:
        numPic = 1
        req = requests.get(urlImage, headers = headers)
        response = req.content
        openfileq = f"media/", i, "_", numPic, ".jpg"
        with open(openfileq, "wb") as file:
            file.write(response)
            print(urlImage,numPic)
        numPic = numPic + 1
```

Вот ошибка:

```
$ C:/python/python.exe c:/projects/parsingpicpdd/parsing-pdd-img.py
https://www.drom.ru/pdd/bilet_1
[<img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608213.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608215.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608216.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608218.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608220.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image 
b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608221.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608223.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608225.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608226.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608228.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608229.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608231.jpg"/>, <img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608233.jpg"/>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\projects\parsingpicpdd\parsing-pdd-img.py", line 18, in <module>
    req = requests.get(urlImage, headers = headers)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 649, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 742, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '<img class="b-image b-image__image" src="https://s.drom.ru/i24227/pdd/tickets/2016/1542608213.jpg"/>'
```

Сами ссылки на изображения я получаю, но при загрузке возникли проблемы, с закачкой другими методами так же не выходило. Пробовал переустановить питон, тоже не помогло.

Comment: Вы из-за этого переустановили Python?

Comment: @Александр да, на другом форуме прочитал это как вариант решения и решил попробовать

Comment: @Jack_oS Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас в `urlImage` не ссылка, а `bs4.element.Tag`...

замените

```
req = requests.get(urlImage, headers = headers)
```

на

```
req = requests.get(urlImage['src'], headers = headers)
```

и

```
openfileq = f"media/", i, "_", numPic, ".jpg"
```

выглядит как... кортеж, попробуйте

```
f'media/{i}_{numPic}.jpg'
```

итоговый рабочий код:

```
import requests, bs4, os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
}

for i in range(1, 40):
    url = 'https://www.drom.ru/pdd/bilet_' + str(i)
    # print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    images = soup.find_all('img', class_='b-image__image')
    # print(images)

    for numPic, urlImage in enumerate(images, 1):
        req = requests.get(urlImage['src'], headers = headers)
        response = req.content
        openfileq = f'media/{i}_{numPic}.jpg'
        with open(openfileq, "wb") as file:
            file.write(response)
            # print(urlImage,numPic)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_urls = 'https://www.drom.ru/pdd/bilet_'

urls_list = [f"{main_urls}{i}" for i in range(1, 41, 1)]

a, b = ('img', 'b-image b-image__image')

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:45.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'}

def get_links_to_images():
    responses = [response.text for response in map(get, urls_list)]
    soups = [BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml') for response in responses]
    soups_object_img = [soups[i].find(a, b) for i in range(40)]
    links_images = [link['src'] for link in soups_object_img if link is not None]
    return links_images

def images_download_and_save(urls):
    if os.path.exists('Images'):
        pass
    else:
        os.makedirs('Images')
    for url in urls:
        file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
        content = get(url, headers = headers).content
        with open(f"Images/{file_name}", "wb") as file:
            file.write(content)
def main():
    urls = get_links_to_images()
    images_download_and_save(urls)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```